# Consider relativity. If a stick accelerates from a stationary state, how will it look like during the acceleration?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

I mean how it will be shortened in the sight of an observer in a stationary coordinate system.

It seems I was not clear enough. If the stick becomes shorter, then while this is happening, the observer should see the two ends have different velocities. Then, how big are they?

Comment: Why do you expect this to yield any different answer than the usual length contraction, $l'=l\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$?

Comment: @Danu i know it will be shortened like this. But this length changing can be realized in different form.

Comment: What do you mean by 'different form'?

Comment: As it stands, I can't quite understand what you are trying to ask. This may indicate that this question is too unclear/does not contain enough information to be useful to this site. Please try to improve the question by adding more information or rephrasing some things. If this is not done, the questions is likely to be closed.

Comment: @Danu  if it is to be shortened. Then different parts of the stick should have different velocity in the stationary observer's eyes. This velocity distribution is what i want to know.

Comment: Unless you have a deformable stick, the stick will be shortened homogeneously.

Comment: @Danu i know. But when you look at it, the both ends have different velocity,right? Because it becomes shorter and shorter.

Comment: I also do not understand what you are asking, but you might be interested that the *actual* visual effect of the length contraction is the [Terrell rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation)

Comment: It sounds like you're on your way to reinventing the Bell spaceship paradox: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=742729

Comment: Upvoting this question because apparently many grad students in physics don't know the answer...

Comment: @ACuriousMind that's interesting but not what i want. I don't take the signal transmission time into consideration.

Comment: @ACuriousMind i mean if the stick is accelerating. then what is its acceleration? because the stick is being shortened, there is a motion of the stick itself(shortening) and a motion of acceleration. so it is complicated here

Comment: @BenCrowell interesting but not what i want. what i want to know it the behavior of the ship itself in your reference.

Comment: @ACuriousMind please have a look at benrg's answer, that is exactly what i want to know:)

Comment: @BenCrowell please have a look at benrg's answer, that is exactly what i want to know:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume

(1) the 'stick' (rod) does not contract according to an observer fixed at any point on the rod and

(2) any point on the rod has constant proper acceleration and

(3) the rod is momentarily at rest at $t=0$ in some inertial frame of reference

then every point on the rod is a [Rindler observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#The_Rindler_observers) which means that every point on the rod has a different proper acceleration!

The worldlines of the ends of the rod and points in between trace hyperbolic world lines as so

[image]

---

> but does it still have a well defined proper length can be shown in
>   the graph?

From the article "[Accelerated Travels](http://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-09/2-09.htm)" at www.mathpages.com:

> Consequently the line from the origin through any point on the
>   hyperbolic path represents the space axis for the co-moving inertial
>   coordinates of the accelerating worldline at that point. The same
>   applies to any other hyperbolic path asymptotic to the same
>   lightlines, so a line from the origin intersects any two such
>   hyperbolas at points that are mutually simultaneous and separated by a
>   constant proper distance (since they are both a fixed proper distance
>   from the origin along their mutual space axis). It follows that in
>   order for a slender "rigid" rod accelerating along its axis to
>   maintain a constant proper length (with respect to its co-moving
>   inertial frames), the parts of the rod must accelerate along a family
>   of hyperbolas asymptotic to the same lightlines, as illustrated below.

[image]

> The x',t' axes represent the mutual co-moving inertial frame of the
>   hyperbolic worldlines where they intersect with the x' axis. All the
>   worldlines have constant proper distances from each other along this
>   axis, and all have the same speed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. seems reasonable. where is the proper length of the rod

Comment: @XiangruLian, let's assume that the world lines of the ends of the rod are the two right-most lines in the spacetime diagram above.  Then, the proper length is the spatial separation of the world lines when $t=0$ since the rod is momentarily at rest in this reference frame then.

Comment: when the rod has a velocity, its axes in Minkowski diagram will change to have an acute angle, isn't it? then the proper length is not parallel to the x axis in your graph. Then where is the proper length?

Comment: @XiangruLian, the ends of the rod are not inertial and, further, do not, in general, have the same momentarily co-moving reference frame.

Comment: yeah.. i see.. but does it still have a well defined proper length can be shown in the graph?

Comment: @XiangruLian, yes, I will update my answer later with a new graph.

Comment: @XiangruLian, updated.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that different parts of the object have to accelerate differently. The details are pretty complicated—when you push one end of an object, transient pressure waves bounce around inside it, and it eventually settles down into a new equilibrium state, which happens to be moving and (in the original reference frame) shorter than before.

A simpler situation is a rocket ship that fires its rockets at a constant rate for a fixed amount of time. When the rockets are turned on and off there will be complicated transients, but in between it will settle into a steady state of constant acceleration, and if it accelerates for long enough you can ignore the transients. The interesting thing about this situation is that, in the steady state, the "top" of the ship (the part farthest from the rockets, which will feel like the top if you're standing in it) has a smaller acceleration than the bottom of the ship. You can measure the difference with any accelerometer, like the one in your smartphone. This wouldn't be true in the Newtonian case, and it seems internally inconsistent at first glance, but you can think of it as being related to the ship's increasing length contraction relative to the original rest frame.

Comment: Yeah, i think you are talking about what i want to know! Could you please give me a reference or explain more details about this? Thank you!